# Scrolling Views with static rows/cols

Tags: android

I'm trying to design a type of view but unsure what is possible and the best approach. 
I'm trying to create a timetable type view with the following properties:

1. Time 'row' across top vertically static and scrollable horizontally
2. Student(or day) 'column' on left side, horizontally static and scrollable vertically
3. 'rows' for each student/day indicating classes at specific times, therefore not all uniform, but total will be = 1 day's worth of classes.
4. each row is split visibly into classes, width indicating duration, title shown in text.
5. Must be able to detect any given class 'touched'
6. 'Rows' must be scrollable (all-way) by touch/fling with time row and left column remaining on screen but scrolling in line with the class data
7. Number of rows is known when the activity is invoked
8. Data for classes is retrieved using a webservice

I hope that's given an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. However I'm not sure where to start with this? I know I can't create anything directly out-of-the-box, so will need 
to create/override. 
(I do currently have all this done for a single student/day with single listview, each item a class, but obviously can't see all timetable in one go and scroll around.)

Do I try and create an all-way scrolling listview? Use a webview and build the timetable in html/js? Use a canvas and draw everything?

I've looked around and seen tutorials by you fabulous people for all those above but then I come to the point of how do I add 'freeze panes' for the row and column I need present at all times? 
Does anyone have any ideas that could help me? 
Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Aus.

Comment: A sketch of what you are trying to create might help.

Comment: Hi, No need for a sketch even, as this is so common. Open excel (or A N other spreadsheet application). Column header only scrolls horiz, row 'header' only scrolls vertical. Those headers appear to 'float' over the data as it scrolls both ways.
Only difference with my requirement is that columns are variable for each row (but rows will be a fixed total width and a known number at draw time)

Answer (score 0):

you might look at using the `<scrollview>` in some combo with other containers like GridView, TableView or something along those lines...